# Are you charged maintenance fees for facilities that are currently being built?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I'm nearing my council report and planning for facility expansion in the coming month.  I'm about to build an access lift to the second floor and suddenly wonder, "Will I be charged the $10 maintenance fee for the lift if it is still being built when the monthly report comes in?"

Experimenting just to find out isn't really an option as this is my first time attempting Classic difficulty and have Ironman turned on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have since verified that facilities under construction when receiving your monthly Council Report DO NOT incur monthly maintenance fees.  As it turns out, this is rather easy to prove:

1. Go to your finances in the situation room to check your current monthly expenses.
2. Go to engineering and begin construction on something with a maintenance fee.
3. Go back to check on your finances in the situation room and you'll see that your monthly expenses have not changed.
4. Finally, you can check your finances moments before and after the facility is completed to well and truly verify that maintenance fees are only incurred when buildings are complete and functional.